# Matlab : Autocompletion in the field of the current directory path

Tags: matlab, autocomplete, path, ide, shortcut

I have been working on Matlab recently and can't manage to auto-complete the string I put when I want to change the current working directory.

Here is an image showing what I want to do : I want to have the Desktop location selected and added to the path by either pressing the TAB button or by pressing the Right arrow.

[image]

I managed to do that by pressing Enter after selecting the right directory. However, when I press enter I lose the focus on the field. Since I'm working with quite long paths, I need to click in the field again to type the next directory.

Basicly, all I want to do is to navigate in this field the same way as I would do in a terminal. Is it possible ?

PS : I have looked at the Preferencies Keyboard Shortcuts. And I have the "Expand or Select Tree Node" set to "Right".

PS 2 : I am using Matlab R2013a if it can help

PS 3 : I run Matlab under RedHat Linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my computer (win7 MATLAB 2014b) it works **if** you use  ` \ ` instead of ` / `. Well, if I put the left slash, then I can tab trough the list and press enter to choose, not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Not working sir, can't get a path using the backslash. Mind that I use a Linux based OS, so the root is '/' anyway.